# How can I make the output return ValueError when x is negative?

Tags: python, list, function, exception

How can I write a function sqrt(f:float) -> float that returns the square root of f when f is non-negative. However, if f is negative, your function should raise a ValueError exception stating that the input value f cannot be negative.

For example:

```
sqrt(4.0)
2.0
sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: input value cannot be negative
```

Here is my code, which doesn't really work... what changes should I make?

```
import math
def sqrt(x):
    try:
        if x > 0:
            return math.sqrt(x)
        else:
            return ("ValueError")
    except ValueError:
        return ("ValueError: input value cannot be negative")
```

Comment: I downvoted because it does not look like you did any research on how to raise errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "return" an error; you `raise` the `ValueError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use `raise` keyword.

```py
import math
def sqrt(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError("input value cannot be negative")
    return math.sqrt(x)
```